# IOS Swift Alamofire JSON Request

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, alamofire

I am trying to make a JSON Request with Alamofire but the response is in Greek and Swift returns:

```
Response
{
    id = 4;
    name = "\U0395\U03bb\U03b1\U03b9\U03cc\U03bb\U03b1\U03b4\U03bf"                
    url = "http://www.gaiaskarpos.com/app/images/categories/olive.png";
}
```

The problem is at name field.

```
//Swift Alamofire Request
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://gaiaskarpos.com/applegetCategores.php",
                   encoding:.JSON).validate().responseJSON{(response)->
                    Void in print("Response Json : \(response.result.value)")
```

Comment: I don't see a real problem there, only maybe in the way how you are printing the result. If you try to get `name` and display it in UI, it works correctly, right?

Comment: Checkout this issue
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/358

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same issue in Arabic/Persian chars and It's my solution:
json variable :

```
{
    message = "\U062f\U0633\U062a\U06af\U0627\U0647 \U0645\U0639\U062a\U0628\U0631 \U0646\U06cc\U0633\U062a";
    status = 0;
}
```

So I casted json to `[String: AnyObject]` :

`var test = json as? [String : AnyObject]
print(test)`

It's fixed. You should give it a try.

Comment: Need cast all response as String?

Comment: I cast all. You should try.

Comment: Yes this is the write way i use for more easy the SwiftyJSON .Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your encoding .JSON? You send .GET-request and you don't need to specify the type of encoding in your request.

Alamofire documentation say:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")
         }
     }
```

So use it. Links -> http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/1.1.3/ and https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

You must specify the type of encoding when you pass parameters in the body of your request. It is for .POST and .PUT requests.

Try to print 'name' to Debug area. Maybe you'll get name in normal encoding... Xcode has the disadvantage: it shows not-UTF8 data in response like '\U0395\U03bb ... ... ... \U03b1\U03b9\' when there is some level of nested data in response.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use NSUTF8StringEncoding with alamofire response

```
encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

Comment: The response is a JSON, not a string.

Comment: @Sulthan You can cast it to Json , Why -1 ??

Comment: All JSON data is already encoded in UTF8. And if the response is a JSON, you can't just parse it as a string.

Answer (score -1):

Try to serialize the JSON with below code this might help you

```
let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
                options: nil, error: nil) as [String : String]
```